# Hand cursor not appearing when hovering over a button in Tkinter for MacOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

My cursor does not show the little hand when hovering over a button in Tkinter for MacOS, and by 'little hand' I mean the standard hand of MacOS that appears when hovering over any button or link (I'm not looking for a custom cursor, I'm looking for the standard one).

Here's some of my code (simplified):

```
import tkinter
from tkmacosx import Button as button

def start():
    print('hi')
    return

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("450x650")

frame= tkinter.Frame(root, bg="#181A1C")
frame.place(relx=.1, rely=.05, relwidth=.8, relheight=.9)
startButton=button(frame, bg="white", text='press for hello', command= start)
startButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I've seen other Tkinter examples on MacOS and they have the same issue with the cursor hand not appearing.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you using threads here? A common rule is that all GUI should be on the main thread, and I think that's even an requirement in Tkinter if I remember correctly.

Comment: I'm new at coding but I don’t think that is the issue, when I add something like `cursor="hand2"` to the button it works just fine, but "hand2" is not the system's cursor that I need.

Comment: If you're new, then I suggest staying away from threads. You'll learn more solutions to problems that are applicable to other areas of programming and threads cause more problems than solutions. Also, they're only used for heavy I/O tasks. However, using GUI in a thread is a problem; even if it might not be *the* problem. It could resolve in undefined behaviour, which means that anything can happen. So I think you should confirm that threading really isn't the issue, by providing a [mre] that doesn't contain threading. It'll also allow people unfamiliar with it to easier answer the question.

Comment: Thank you, yes I agree, I have simplified the code, unfortunately the hand cursor not appearing seems to be a Tkinter issue given it doesn't work at its most basic level. Yet I can't find anything about it online.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the native mac pointing hand by saying `cursor='pointinghand'`.